# How to open modal form when button is clicked using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is what I currently have on "dir.php". What must happen here is that after clicking the add button, the modal form should show up. Will you please check my code and tell me what is the solution? Thanks!

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-md btnAdd" role="button"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>Add</a>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
            {
                $(".btnAdd").click(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "modal.php",
                        success: function(returndata){
                              $('#myModal').modal('show');
                        },
                        dataType: "html"
                    });
                });


            });
</script>
```

and on "modal.php" contains the modal form

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="form1" action="" method="post">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name1" />
                        <label class="control-label">Branch Address</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bAddress1" />
                        <label  class="control-label">Officer-in-Charge</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="officer1" />
                        <label  class="control-label">Contact Number</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contactN1" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="btn" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding your code to jsfiddle.net and include the link in your question so people who are interested in answering your question can check the code easier.

Comment: your ajax function work properly?

Comment: your $(".btnAdd") click should contain the showing of the modal not an ajax request try doing something like this `$(".btnAdd").click(function() {
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
`

Comment: @guradio it did not work for me

Comment: do you see any error in console?

Comment: @guradio there are no error shown but when I clicked the button, the modal did not show up

Comment: can you create demo ni jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting:

```
<div id="myModal" ...></div>
```

into **dir.php**, then try adding:

```
$('#myModal').html(returndata);
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

into the `success:` method.

Comment: You didn't get any dynamic data from modal.php, why not just insert html into dir.php, and use javascript to show it.

Answer (score 0):

edit dir.php code :

```
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-md btnAdd" role="button"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>Add</a>
    <style type="text/css">
        #myModal {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <!-- add div for show data  -->
       <div id="myModal">

       </div>
    <!-- end -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
                {
                    $(".btnAdd").click(function(){
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "modal.php",
                            success: function(returndata){
                                  // $('#myModal').modal('show');

                                     $('#myModal').html(returndata);
                                     $('#myModal').modal('show');
                            },
                            dataType: "html"
                        });
                    });


                });
    </script>
```